# Approximating expectation with Taylor series

Tags: bayesian, inference, expected-value, approximate-inference

I want to get the second-order Taylor approximation for an expectation.

I have the following distribution, which is a [Generalized Dirichlet distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Dirichlet_distribution) with parameters $\boldsymbol\alpha$ and $\boldsymbol\beta$.

\begin{equation}
q(\boldsymbol\theta\mid\boldsymbol\alpha,\boldsymbol\beta)=\prod_i^n\frac{\Gamma(\alpha_{i} + \beta_{i})}{\Gamma(\alpha_i)\Gamma(\beta_i)} \theta_{i}^{\alpha_{i} -1} (1-\sum_{j=1}^{i}\theta_{j})^{\gamma_{i}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \gamma_i= 
\begin{cases}
    \beta_i - \alpha_{i+1} - \beta_{i+1}& \text{if } i\neq n\\
    \beta_i-1             & \text{if } i= n
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

After bayesian inference, I want to estimate the parameters. I think that [taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_expansions_for_the_moments_of_functions_of_random_variables) can help me to approximate this expectation:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}_\theta\sim q\left[\frac{\theta_i}{\sum_i\theta_i\varphi_i}\right]
\end{equation}

Second-order Taylor series is expressed as follows, where $H$ is the Hessian matrix and $Tr$ is the trace operator.

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[f(\boldsymbol\theta)\right] \approx f(\mathbb{E}\left[\boldsymbol\theta\right]) + \frac{1}{2} Tr\left(H(\mathbb{E}\left[\boldsymbol\theta\right]) Var(\boldsymbol\theta)\right)
$$

However, because of that sole component ($\theta_i$), I don't know how to express $\frac{\theta_i}{\sum_i\theta_i\varphi_i}$ in terms of $\boldsymbol\theta$, so I will have $\mathbb{E}_\theta\sim q\left[f(\boldsymbol\theta)\right]$.

Any suggestions on this? or maybe a different approach?

Comment: If f is a function of $\theta_i$,  then you replace all the random variable $\theta_i$, by mean of $\theta_i$, and then calculate f?

Comment: 1) I tried making a change of variable. I thought that introducing the component $\theta_i$ in the numerator will give a GDD with different parameters. However, that change is not trivial since the parameters work as a chain (the previous and next one are used in $\gamma_i$). 2) I don't see how to express $f(\theta_i)$ can you elaborate a little more? 3) I was thinking in doing this $\frac{\theta_k \delta(k=i)}{\sum_k \theta_k\varphi_k}$, is it a valid expression of $f(\boldsymbol\theta)$